# Scanner reading a text file from command line using a loop, but the loop will not break

Tags: java, command-line, java.util.scanner, java-io

So I want to read in a .text or a .data file in java from the commandline using

```
java name < filename.data
```

Here is the code:

```java
        ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
             System.out.println("Reading line");
             String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
             System.out.println("The line is: " + line);
             if (line.equals("") || line.isEmpty()) {
                 System.out.println("Found blank area");
                  break;
              }  
             System.out.println("Adding to arrayList");
             input.add(line);

        }
        System.out.println("Read in was successful");
```

The line "system.out.println("Read in was successful"); is never reached. It seems the 'if' statement used to break the loop after reading is also never reached. It doesn't even seem that the loop returns to the top. This is my output (the method does successfully read in all my text file)

```
Reading line
The line is: car
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is: mega
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is: bed
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is: stop
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is: game
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is: pots
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is: arc
Adding to arrayList
```

I would expect one more run which indicates that the program has reached the end of the file by printing out "Found blank area".

So it seems to successfully read line, but cannot seem to break. My program doesn't crash, it just "hangs" there if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not reaching `if (line.equals("") || line.isEmpty())` code as I think there is no empty lines in the empty file ,I tried to ran the code and got desired output with input file content as

**Output**

```
Reading line
The line is: car
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is: mega
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is: bed
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is: stop
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is: game
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is: pots
Adding to arrayList
Reading line
The line is:
Found blank area
Read in was successful
```

**Input file**

```
car
mega
bed
stop
game
pots

arc
```